# Method keeps triggering database

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs, angular-services

This *LanguageService* class is injected into my components so it can get the translation for my component.

It checks if the key is in the Map;
If it's not in there: It gets the translations from the server the first time and adds it into a Map (dictionary).
If it's there: It takes the values of the Map instead of going to the server again.

The strange part is that my log states it found the key and will return the value in map but when I check Fiddler, it registers a call to the server?

```
@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {
```

My variable

```
  private loadedTranslations: Map<string, Observable<ITranslate[]>> = new Map();
```

The place where my consol.log & Fiddler disagree

```
  public mapTranslation(url: string, key: string): Observable<ITranslate[]> {

    if (this.loadedTranslations.has(key) == false) {
      console.log("I don't have a key named " + key + ". I'll have to connect to the server");
      this.loadedTranslations.set(key, this.getTranslationFromServer(url));
    }
    else {
      console.log("I have " + key + ". I'll return the values for it!!");
    }

    console.log("Returning Translation for " + url + " with key " + key);

    return this.loadedTranslations.get(key);
  }
```

This method does a call to the server for the values

```
  getTranslationFromServer(url: string): Observable<ITranslate[]> {
    console.log("getTranslationFromServer is called");

    return this._http.get(url)
      .map(this._helperService.extractData)
      .catch(this._helperService.handleErrors);
  }
}
```

An example output is this:

**First hit**
*Log*

> I don't have a key named database. I'll have to connect to the server
>   **getTranslationFromServer is called**
>   Returning Translation for Database/Translations with key database

*Fiddler*

> GET http://localhost:55041/Database/Translations 200 OK (application/json)

**Second hit**
*Log*

> I contain 1 keys
>   I have database. I'll return the values for it!!
>   Returning Translation for /Database/Translations with key database

*Fidler*

> GET http://localhost:55041/Database/Translations 200 OK
>   (application/json)

I tried changing from an Observable to a Promise but no luck.

Why does Fiddler states it queries the database but I don't see *getTranslationFromServer is called* two times?
How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have have edited my Map, instead of holding and Observable it now just holds ITranslate[].

I suppose that the trip to the database happens in memory.

```
@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {
  private loadedTranslations: Map<string, ITranslate[]> = new Map();


  public mapTranslation(url: string, key: string): ITranslate[] {
    if (this.loadedTranslations.has(key) == false) {
      this.getTranslationFromServer(url).subscribe(a => this.loadedTranslations.set(key, a), e => this._helperService.handleError(e));
    }
    else {
      console.log("I have " + key + ". I'll return the values for it!!");
    }

    return this.loadedTranslations.get(key);
  }

  getTranslationFromServer(url: string): Observable<ITranslate[]> {
    return this._http.get(url)
      .map(this._helperService.extractData)
      .catch(this._helperService.handleErrors);
  }
}
```